Python Pandas df, subtract minutes (in time duration column) from time column
I have a pandas df with Time, Duration (in minutes, integer format), and Duration in timedelta format. The EndTime column has been parsed to time format.



id
EndTime
Duration_Minutes
Duration_TimeDelta




1
00:53:18
120
0 days 02:00:00


2
01:04:38
35
0 days 00:35:00


3
05:04:38
5
0 days 00:05:00



I wanted to created a new column: StartTime
I tried various things:
from datetime import timedelta
 df['StartTimeEstimate'] = df['EndTime'] - pd.Timedelta(hours=0, minutes=df['Minutes'], seconds=0)

or
df['StartTimeEstimate'] = df['EndTime'] - timedelta(minutes = df['Minutes'])

But couldn't quite work out a StartTime.
Ideally, I would like to see end StartTime to be:
22:53:18
12:29:38
04:59:38

There is no df['Minutes'] in your df.

Is that supposed to be df['Duration_Minutes']?

yes, it was a typo. Thanks for spotting it! I corrected it in the question now.

You can't add time and timedelta, as the former doesn't have information about the date.
So if 'EndTime' is of type time, you can first convert it to str and use pd.to_datetime to convert it to datetime. Then you can just subtract  the timedelta from the datetime:
df["StartTimeEstimate"] = (
    pd.to_datetime(df["EndTime"].astype(str)) - df["Duration_TimeDelta"]
).dt.time

   id   EndTime  Duration_Minutes Duration_TimeDelta StartTimeEstimate
0   1  00:53:18               120    0 days 02:00:00          22:53:18
1   2  01:04:38                35    0 days 00:35:00          00:29:38
2   3  05:04:38                 5    0 days 00:05:00          04:59:38

If 'EndTime' is of type str, you can remove the .astype(str).
